# MSBuild / YUICompressor error

Tags: msbuild, yui

Using the following msbuild config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/MsBuild/2003">

    <UsingTask
        TaskName="CompressorTask"
        AssemblyFile="Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.dll" />

    <PropertyGroup>
        <JavaScriptOutputFile Condition=" '$(JavaScriptOutputFile)'=='' ">..\..\site.se\javascript\javascript.min.js</JavaScriptOutputFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="CompressorTask">
        <ItemGroup>
          <JavaScriptFiles Include="..\..\site.se\javascript\javascript.js"/>
        </ItemGroup>
        <CompressorTask
             JavaScriptFiles="@(JavaScriptFiles)"
             ObfuscateJavaScript="True"
             PreserveAllSemicolons="True"
             DisableOptimizations="False"
             EncodingType="utf-8"
             DeleteJavaScriptFiles="false"
             LineBreakPosition="-1"
             JavaScriptOutputFile="$(JavaScriptOutputFile)"
             LoggingType="HardcoreBringItOn"
             ThreadCulture="en-us"
             IsEvalIgnored="false" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

I get the following error:

> Scripts.xml(14,11): error MSB4067:  -element under
>   -element is unknown. (translated from swedish)

I'm using the 32bit .NET 2.0 version of MsBuild.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put an `ItemGroup` in a target with MSBuild for .NET 2. You have to use the `CreateItem` task or put it outside of the target. In your case you don't seem to need to dynamically create the `JavaScriptFiles` item so you just have to put it outside of the target.

---

**Outside**:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <JavaScriptFiles Include="..\..\site.se\javascript\javascript.js"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CompressorTask">
    <CompressorTask
         JavaScriptFiles="@(JavaScriptFiles)"
         ObfuscateJavaScript="True"
         PreserveAllSemicolons="True"
         DisableOptimizations="False"
         EncodingType="utf-8"
         DeleteJavaScriptFiles="false"
         LineBreakPosition="-1"
         JavaScriptOutputFile="$(JavaScriptOutputFile)"
         LoggingType="HardcoreBringItOn"
         ThreadCulture="en-us"
         IsEvalIgnored="false" />
  </Target>
```

**Using `CreateItem`**:

```
  <Target Name="CompressorTask">
    <CreateItem Include="..\..\site.se\javascript\javascript.js">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="JavaScriptFiles"/>
    </CreateItem>

    <CompressorTask
         JavaScriptFiles="@(JavaScriptFiles)"
         ObfuscateJavaScript="True"
         PreserveAllSemicolons="True"
         DisableOptimizations="False"
         EncodingType="utf-8"
         DeleteJavaScriptFiles="false"
         LineBreakPosition="-1"
         JavaScriptOutputFile="$(JavaScriptOutputFile)"
         LoggingType="HardcoreBringItOn"
         ThreadCulture="en-us"
         IsEvalIgnored="false" />
  </Target>
```